# Use already uploaded picture in ezpublish Article

Tags: image, gallery, image-gallery, ezpublish

In my article datatype, I've an ezimage field which look like that:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZGR3.png

I can upload/drag and drop pictures, set a description, it's work fine.

But I can't figured out how to use already uploaded pictures, ma Media Library is full of pictures but I don't know how to use them in my field.. I think and hope there is a way to add this functionality without overriding ezimage datatype.

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Image objects in your Media Library, you should use an Object Relation field in the Content Classes you want to use this object from. You would then be able to browse for images when editing the content.

Multiple images would also work, by using an Object Relation List instead of a single Object Relation.

Which version of eZ are you dealing with here ?